# Using @TextBoxFor with @model IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a primary controller/view that uses an `@model IEnumerable<ReportModel>` for the strongly typed view. I would like to use `@TextBoxFor()` but this does not work with the `IEnumerable` (or, at least, intellisense does not like it).

Is it necessary to create a partial view or something else to allow use of the strongly typed model in creating form elements?

Comment: Does IEnumerable<ReportModel> not indicate that there could be lots of results. How could they be put into a single textbox?

Comment: The view shows multiple rows from the IEnumberable but I would like to present a collection of textboxes for filtering purposes that I can submit to the controller and the EF repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the IEnumerable to be an IList and loop through the records of your collection and choose the properties that will appear in the textboxes:

```
@model IList<ReportModel>

@for(int i = 0; i < model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => model[i].Property)
}
```

Thanks to Stephen Muecke for the correction.

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to split up the views to a header with a single model a detail with the IEnumberable model.  This is far easier.  In the end I just did a record.First().Property outside of the loop.

Comment: The does not work and binding will fail when you submit the form. You need a `for` loop (and the model must be `IList<T>` or a custom `EditorTemplate` for `ReportModel`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the correction - only had to do something like this once before and I forgot about it.